# I want to update TableViewCell in TableView everytime after click one button

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

In tableviewcell, when click add button, I added one viewcontroller in cell contentview.
In this controller, when click add button or close button, viewcontroller will be removed from superview.
After that cell data should be updated. such as add product button.
Therefore, I tried to show viewcontroller in cellcontentview when click add button everytime.
But it is working only 2 times. After 2times, app is not working anymore to show viewcontroller in cellcontentview.

```
    cell.addAction = { item in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print(item.addonActive)
            self.menuView?.mTableView!.beginUpdates()
            self.menuView?.mTableView!.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            self.menuView?.mTableView!.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            self.menuView?.mTableView!.endUpdates()
        }
    }
```

If you have experienced in this field, please give me best way.
Thanks

Comment: Please review [ask].

Comment: Sorry, that is still not nearly enough information to try and help you. Take a few minutes (5 or 10 or 15 or 30 minutes) to write out details of what you are trying to do. The code you just posted in your comment doesn't look like it will do anything, other than "refresh" the current row (which you shouldn't do like that anyway). And, please don't post code like that in a comment, it is not readable - edit your question as shown.

Comment: I am sorry. I can not edit question now. well,  I introduced cell delegate function in tableview cell. And then I  used delegate function in viewcontroller. As you can see in above code, there is item.addonActive value. This value can be true or false.
After click button, this value should be changed like this from false to true.
After this, app should reload cell again.  but app is refreshing data only two time.
And then item.addonActive value is still existing as true value. So,I can not reload cell again because of itme.addonActive value.

Comment: If StackOverflow won't allow you to edit your question, delete this one and start a new one. But... include enough information to get help. Take a look at [mre].